# Postgresql result does not match the database using mybatis

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

config.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.###.mapper.EmployeeMapper" >
    <resultMap id="EmployeeMap" type="com.###.model.Employee">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="name" property="name" />
        <result column="type" property="type"/>
        <result column="authority" property="authority"/>
        <result column="tel" property="tel"/>
        <result column="extra" property="extra"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getById" parameterType="java.lang.String"  resultMap="EmployeeMap" >
        SELECT  * from employee WHERE  id=#{id}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

test code

```
@Test
void insert() {
    // 插入新行
    Employee employee = new Employee("", "张三", "教授", null, "13122107768", null);
    employeeMapper.insert(employee);
    // 查询新行
    Assert.assertEquals(employee,employeeMapper.getById(employee.getId()));
}
```

result

Expected: `Employee(id=28, name=张三, type=教授, authority=null, tel=13122107768, extra=null)`

Actual: `Employee(id=28, name=张三, type=教授, authority=13122107768, tel=13122107768, extra=张三)`

[image: database view]

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The entity class must have a no-argument constructor